# How to send GuildDelete to specific channel?

Tags: discord.js

I need to send my `guildDelete` and `guildCreate` in specific channel there is a code:

```js
client.on("guildDelete", (guild, msg) => {
    client.channels.get(`707291237782257776`).send(heh)
    var heh = (`
    Я **Ушел** :outbox_tray: с сервера **${guild.name}**. Информация о нем:
    Акроним и ID: **${guild.nameAcronym} | ${guild.id}**
    Основатель: **${guild.owner} (\`${guild.owner.user.tag}\`)**
    Количество участников: **${guild.memberCount}**
    Роли: **${guild.roles.size}**
    Каналы: **${guild.channels.size}**
    Создана: **${guild.createdAt.toString().slice(4, -32)}**
    Иконка: ${guild.iconURL}
    **Это наш ${client.guilds.size}-ый сервер!**`),
        bot
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Leaved a guild: ${guild.name} | ${guild.id}`);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Error: `TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Since discord.js v12 you now need to use `cache` to access the `channels` collection, you also have other properties you can't access in your code since you didn't use `cache`:

```js
client.on("guildDelete", (guild, msg) => {
  client.channels.cache.get(`707291237782257776`).send(heh)
  var heh =  (`
Я **Ушел** :outbox_tray: с сервера **${guild.name}**. Информация о нем:
Акроним и ID: **${guild.nameAcronym} | ${guild.id}**
Основатель: **${guild.owner} (\`${guild.owner.user.tag}\`)**
Количество участников: **${guild.memberCount}**
Роли: **${guild.roles.cache.size}**
Каналы: **${guild.channels.cache.size}**
Создана: **${guild.createdAt.toString().slice(4, -32)}**
Иконка: ${guild.iconURL}
**Это наш ${client.guilds.cache.size}-ый сервер!**`),
    bot
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Leaved a guild: ${guild.name} | ${guild.id}`);
  }, 1000);
});
```